# jQuery click function works intermittently with if/else

Tags: jquery, if-statement, click, this

Building a shopping list app which on click, crosses out the specified item. If that item is clicked again, it should be restored to its original state. I have an if/else statement to check if the "ixtem" class has been applied yet. For some reason, if there are multiple items on the list, the if/else statement runs several times, even though I've used $(this) selector:

```
$('.crossout').click(function() {

    if ($(this).closest('.newitem').hasClass('xitem')) {
        $(this).closest('.newitem').removeClass('xitem');
        console.log('remove x');
    }

    else {
        $(this).closest('.newitem').addClass('xitem');
        console.log('x out');   
    }

})
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant HTML?

Comment: Uh, there's `toggleClass` for that ?

Comment: you have multiple .crossout elements that have attached multiple click event handlers too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('li').each(function(i) {
        $(this).click(function() {
            $(this).toggleClass('crossOut');
        });
    });
});
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ackerman/nF4Jd/